# Updating particular key's value of hashmap stored in file

Tags: java, android, file, serialization, hashmap

I am using below code to write HashMap to a file.I want to update particular value of HashMap in file.Suppose I want to update value of key `"b"` keeping other values same.How can I do that?

```
  HashMap settinglist=new HashMap();
settinglist.put("a",”abc”);
settinglist.put("b",”def”);
settinglist.put("c",”hij”);
settinglist.put("d",”klm”);
settinglist.put("e", “nop”);
SettingsObjectSerializer.serializeObject(getApplicationContext(),settinglist);
```

SettingsObjectSerializer

```
 public class SettingsObjectSerializer {
        private final static String FILENAME = "retrytimeout";
        private static HashMap mSettingList = null;
        public static boolean serializeObject(Context ctx, HashMap retrytimeout) {
            boolean success = false;
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                os.writeObject(retrytimeout);
                os.close();
                fos.close();
                if(retrytimeout == null) {
                    mSettingList = null;
                }
                success = true;
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }
        public static HashMap getSerializedObject(Context ctx) {
            if (mSettingList != null) {
                return mSettingList;
            }
            try {
                FileInputStream fis =  ctx.openFileInput(FILENAME);
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                mSettingList = (HashMap) is.readObject();
                is.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mSettingList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the serialized object into a HashMap then use the HashMap method `put(Object key, Object value);` to replace the old value for key "b" with a new value (since there can only be one unique key). Then serialize the HashMap and save it again. 
Example:

```
        //Your initialization
        HashMap settinglist=new HashMap();
        settinglist.put("a","abc");
        settinglist.put("b","def");
        settinglist.put("c","hij");
        settinglist.put("d","klm");
        settinglist.put("e", "nop");
        SettingsObjectSerializer.serializeObject(getApplicationContext(),settinglist);

        //Change the value linked to key "b" to "NEWVALUE"
        HashMap settings = SettingsObjectSerializer.getSerializedObject(getApplicationContext());
        settings.put("b", "NEWVALUE");
        SettingsObjectSerializer.serializeObject(getApplicationContext(),settings);
```

Comment: there is NO method `.replace` for `HashMap`

Comment: Sorry used to the java method, you can just use put("b", "NEWVALUE") to replace the old value. Edited the answer.

Comment: after doing this `SettingsObjectSerializer.getSerializedObject(mContext);` gives null pointer exception..any idea why?

Comment: Is mContext null? If it is ctx.openFileInput(FILENAME); will throw that exception.

Comment: no its not null..it was working previously before updating hashmap

Comment: And did you save the hashmap again after updating it? I works for me, but if you can write the error it will be easier to localize.

Comment: it gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException`  at `SettingsObjectSerializer.getSerializedObject(mContext)`

Comment: It makes no sense for a static method call to give you a nullpointer exception, are you sure it is not happening inside the method getSerializedObject(mContext)?

Comment: it might be happening inside the method getSerializedObject(mContext) but it was not happening before updating the value..if i uninstall the app and then install again it runs fine but after updating value if i close app and then open ti gives me exception in the fragment where I am using this method